# How to document an array key / value meaning with PHPDoc?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have an array that represents some mapping between strings. The key and the value both have (business) meaning. For example, in the array:

```php
[
    '10000' => 'f4970340-9cb7-4380-948c-54e0d1556d58',
    '20000' => '665cdd7d-dbef-4c0a-963e-467a68fa097f',
    '84000' => '5b7f0abc-a515-4409-8b70-f1aafeef5038',
    … # more entries
]
```

`10000`, `20000` and `84000` represent customers. The UUIDs represent groups to which the customers belong.

Is there any convention / best-practice of how to document the **meaning** of the strings? I am not talking about documenting the types (=strings).

Something like:

```php
    /**
     * @return string[]
     * [
     *     customerId => groupId,
     *     …
     * ]
     */
    public function getCustomerIdGroupIdMap(): array
    {}
```

Answer (score 1):

In all the cases I've seen and used, the [text description](https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/guides/docblocks.html#description) is the best place to add specific notes to clarify the details.

```
<?php

/**
 * Returns an array keyed by the customer ID. The values represent the group ID. 
 * @return array
 */
public function getCustomerIdGroupIdMap(): array
{}
```

Alternatively, using the [description of the return type](https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html#description) can be used.

```
<?php

/**
 * @return array Keyed by the customer ID. The values represent the group ID. 
 */
public function getCustomerIdGroupIdMap(): array
{}
```